# Performance: else if vs if in function that already returned

Tags: c++, performance

Is there any difference in performance between using else if / if in a function that returns something? I mean, if the function already returned, it won't execute the next if anyways, which is the purpose of else if, right? I wrote a small code snippet to illustrate that

```
#include <iostream>

bool foo(int x)
{
if (x == 3) return 1;
else if (x == 4) return 1; //using only if here has the performance of else if?
return 0;
}

int main()
{
int x = 4;
std::cout << foo(x);
std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No difference on any sane compiler. Look at resulting assembly at https://gcc.godbolt.org/ to be sure.

Comment: They'll generate identical assembly with some optimization level on a modern compiler. The `else` is redundant IMHO.

Comment: If you're worrying about performance of code at this sort of micro-scale, you have a future as a premature optimiser ahead of you.   Premature optimisation - worrying about optimising code constructs before there is any evidence there is a need to, and lovingly hand-crafting code for hours to achieve no measurable benefit - is generally the same as time wasting.

Comment: @Peter - ... or a code-obfuscation engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should all be the same, one way to check for better performace is to compare your assembly code, you can use tools like godbolt.org, usually the code that generates fewer instructions performs faster.

by the way, it is better if you compare for "return 0" before the other two cases, as almost 100% of the times your input argument is not 3 or 4,

```
if (x != 3) return 0;
return 1;
```

is much better than

```
if (x == 3) return 1; 
return 0;
```

Comment: Returning if `x != 3` first will give different behaviour for the OP's code if `x == 4`   (which is returning `1` if `x` is ether of two values).